xcode EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102484000)
How to solve this issue?  Working on a CodenameOne bare-bones example app (no changes by me) it builds and installs fine, but xcode stops running at the very start of the app, with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102484000).  The backtrace does not lead back to any of the source code in my project (other than the Stub), and if I stop xcode, the simulator that it brought up and installed the app to, can run the app just fine.  attempts to fix involve going to xcode Beta 16 and Mac OS Sonoma Beta in hopes of a fix - no luck there.
I went back to xcode 15.2 but staying with the beta Mac OS since I don't want to wipe the installation completely.  Developing with Intellij Community Edition 2022.3.2 and when running as a desktop app or via the local CodenameOne simulator, everything works without complaint; the 'bad access' problem only shows up after Intellij hands off the local IOS build to xcode and it installs and runs the project either on my own devices or a simulator.

There's an issue with newer versions of xcode which seems to be related to our use of OpenGL. We're in the process of migrating to Metal which would hopefully fix that issue but it got sidetracked due to other priorities.
As a workaround download simulator 17.0 which seems to work.

I had a 17.4 and 17.5 iPadPro in my list, tried those with the same problem but after your answer I went with the 18.0 and that one works.  Thanks!
